# AFNetworking async download GIF with placeholder

Tags: ios, afnetworking, gif

I've been using AFNetworking for downloading UIImage async with placeholder, it works fine with JPEG and PNG, however I'm using a [library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) for my GIF pictures. It works well when I'm doing it in sync. However I would like to use AFNetworking to download the image in async while showing a placeholder image in the ImageView. How can I do that? Thanks!

Here are my codes:

```
- (void) downloadAllImagesForComment
{
    if (_imageLinkList.count > 0)
    {
        if (images == nil)
            images = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *URL in _imageLinkList) {
            if ([images objectForKey:[URL objectForKey:@"link"]] == nil)
            {
                /*
                 * imageType = 0 <= other
                 * imageType = 1 <= gif
                 */
                int imageType = 0;

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[URL objectForKey:@"link"]];
                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"Retrieving imageData...");
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Retrived imageData.");
                uint8_t c;
                [imageData getBytes:&c length:1];

                switch (c) {
                    case 0xFF:
                        NSLog(@"image/jpeg");
                        imageType = 0;
                        break;
                    case 0x89:
                        NSLog(@"image/png");
                        imageType = 0;
                        break;
                    case 0x47:
                        NSLog(@"image/gif");
                        imageType = 1;
                        break;
                    case 0x49:
                        imageType = 0;
                        break;
                    case 0x4D:
                        NSLog(@"image/tiff");
                        imageType = 0;
                        break;
                }

                UIImageView *temp_imageView;
                if (imageType == 1)
                {
                // GIF IMAGE SHOULD BE INITIALIZED HERE!!!!!!
//                    image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:imageData];
                }
                else
                {

                    temp_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 250)];
                    [temp_imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patch_la"]];
                }

                [images setValue:temp_imageView forKey:[URL objectForKey:@"link"]];

                NSLog(@"Done downloading image: %@", [URL objectForKey:@"link"]);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It has async animated Gif support built in.

After including the library, it's simple (just have the NSURL point to the remote Gif):

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){}];
```